# Apple developer certs - what to back up

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm new to iOS development. I know this has been asked so many times, but I'm still confused. We created a new developer.apple.com organization and I have invited my personal Apple ID as an admin, then registered my personal Apple ID within Xcode. From there I opened Team -> "View Details". To create the signing identities, I simply clicked "Create" next to iOS Development and iOS Distribution. Xcode did all the work and I never created a certificate signing request.

We now have a iOS Development (in my name) and Distribution (in the company name) certificates. I have created an App ID and a provisioning profile for wildcard (development) and explicit app ID (distribution).

Now my question is - what do I need to back up from my Keychain and why? It seems I can just re-download everything I need from developer.apple.com. For fun, after doing all this, I deleted the iPhone Developer / iPhone Distribution certs from my keychain, after backing them up, just to see what would happen. Restarting Xcode -> Accounts -> Team -> "View Details" -> "Download All" seemed to download the same private keys I just deleted from my Keychain, which is good.

That suggests to me it's not really important that I back those up. I've heard some say that you absolutely must back up the CSR, but since I never created one, I'm rather confused. My assumption is that Xcode automatically created a transient CSR which I have no access to. The manual CSR route also creates a public and private key pair in your Keychain, and some say to back those up for sure. Since I didn't create a CSR, I only have a cert and private key. No public key was created / registered by Xcode.

If my machine spontaneously combusts, it seems I don't need to recover anything from a backup. Just install xcode, add my Apple ID, and use Download All to retrieve the certs / private keys. Is there something I am missing? I have Time Machine backups to recover from, but I'm curious which assets I should preserve so the rest of our organization can continue to update the app should I, or my computer, vaporize.

Answer (score 9):

You don't **need** to back up anything. Instead, if you lose your private key or other unrecoverable bits of your developer profile, you **can** reset everything and create all-new keys, certificates, etc. for your account and revoke the old ones.

You **can** back everything up if you want, and it's easy. In Xcode's Account Preferences, [export your developer profile](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev8a2822e0b) to a file and back up that file. The profile is encrypted for safety and includes things you cannot re-download from the Apple Developer Center like your private key. You can use this as a backup, and also to easily set up your developer account(s) on multiple Macs.

To export your profile, open the Accounts tab of Xcode's preferences. Click the ⋯⃝ (three dots in a circle icon) in the bottom left area and choose “Export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets…”.

(In older versions of Xcode, the icon was a gear and the menu item was  “Export Developer Accounts…”).

Answer (score 7):

> what do I need to back up from my Keychain and why?

Nothing. In a worst case scenario everything can be retrieved / regenerated from the Member Center. Just don't forget your Apple ID and password.